# How to test cloud function using firebase emulator

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have installed the firebase tools to be able to use the firebase emulator for cloud functions.

Now that I have installed the tools, what I need to do to use the emulator to test a cloud function after I create it locally using vs code?

I just write my code into an index.js file and then run the emulator or there is a special way to proceed?

Comment: Have you checked [run functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) part of the documentation? It's a single command `firebase emulators:start --only functions` mostly.

Comment: ok, but in my code I need to add something to connect with emulator?

Comment: The same page explains what additional changes you need to make in your code. In this case, it would be using the `connectFunctionsEmulator()` function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have node.js code that use require instead of import, not sure if the example can be applied also to node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your Cloud Function using the Firebase Emulator Suite and after [installing it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#install_the_local_emulator_suite), you can optionaly make [some configurations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite), but you can also follow these instructions based on [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/pkgvFNPdiEs?t=114) as an easy way to start your tests:

1. `firebase init`
2. Select the products you need.
3. Enter your project ID and other information.
4. Select Functions emulator.
5. Select the port to use (it could be the default port 5001 for Cloud Functions).

After setting your Firebase project, now start up your emulator with:
`firebase emulators:start`

There you can view status and logs by clicking at localhost link.

To get details about how to Connect your app to the Cloud Functions Emulator, you can follow [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions).

The Emulator Suite is supplemented by other prototype and test tools as [Cloud Functions testing tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#what_other_tools_for_testing_exist), which is integrated by:

1. The Cloud Functions emulator, part of the Emulator Suite.
2. The [Cloud Functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell), which allows for interactive, iterative functions prototyping and development.
3. The [Firebase Test SDK for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), a Node.js with mocha framework for functions development.

In VS Code, you can easily emulate functions by sending code you want to run to the Firebase CLI, as described at the end of this [Doug Stevenson’s post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/09/testing-functions-locally-with-cloud).

This command will run test code from a file redirected through standard input:

`$ firebase experimental:functions:shell < tests.js`

Comment: Mainly what is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#web-version-9) is for web library not nodejs ?

Comment: Yes, at this moment the emulator **for Cloud Functions** basically works for Web, Android, and Swift, as you can see in [this table](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite#feature-matrix). Node.js Admin SDK isn’t available at this moment.