# How to connect Firebase emulator in Swift by using typescript?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing Swift app connecting Firebase emulator in Typescript.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFunctions
import FirebaseFunctionsSwift

@main
struct HelloApp: App {
    
    init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
       
        //Auth
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9099)
        //Storage
        Storage.storage().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9199)
        //Firestore
        let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        settings.host = "localhost:8080"
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        settings.isSSLEnabled = false
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        //Cloud Function
        Functions.functions().useEmulator(withHost: "http://localhost", port: 5001)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainContent()
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error.
`[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (14ed17248) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.`

And logs file, I got this error `expected an unsecured JWT, the emulator does not validate JWTs and IS NOT SECURE`.

How should I fix those.
Please teach me those.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and change the code by moving the `Firestore.firestore().settings` to right after calling `FirebaseApp.configure()`
Also be sure that you still have to set the[FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) env variable to your localhost as the local host needs to be authorized as a Firebase user using the [authorisation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).
Check for a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509099/how-to-test-cloud-function-using-firebase-emulator)